# Структура и Marshal.SizeOf - cannot be marshaled as an unmanaged structure...

Tags: c#

Приветствую.

Имею такой код (C#), который обращается к C++ дллке (не /clr!), перекидывает ей структуру, чтобы та в свою очередь заполнила структуру данными и вернула её соответственно:
https://pastebin.com/DPuBeqBX

Ошибка начала появляться после того, как я добавил (так как появилась необходимость получить список файлов в торренте и отдать его вместе с базовыми данными, которые уже и так возвращаю нормально) в TorrentInfoType структуру вот этот кусок (и в С++ часть соответственно тоже):

```
// Files list in .torrent
[MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)]
public TorrentInfoType_FilesList[] files;
```

Без этого куска, работает нормально.
Ошибка соответственно возникает вот тут:
int tempSize = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(TorrentInfoType));

И просто для референса, на стороне С++ структуры выглядят так:
https://pastebin.com/43RDUdQx

И потом в С++ной части в функции dll_TorrentGetInfo я вызываю функцию для копирования в структуру которая потом возвращается в C#:

```
void TorrentInfo::CopyInfo(TorrentInfoType* dest) const
{
  dest->IsValid      = IsValid();
  dest->name         = _wcsdup(GetNameW().c_str());
  dest->hash         = _wcsdup(GetHashW().c_str());
  dest->creationDate = GetCreationDate();
  dest->creator      = _wcsdup(GetCreatorW().c_str());
  dest->comment      = _wcsdup(GetCommentW().c_str());
  dest->IsPrivate    = IsPrivate();
  dest->totalSize    = GetTotalSize();
  dest->filesCount   = GetFilesCount();
  dest->pieceLength  = GetPieceLength();
  dest->piecesCount  = GetPiecesCount();    

  // TODO: Fill files list.
  // ...
}
```

Поясните пожалуйста новичку, что делаю не так, и как можно исправить проблему :-\